# How do I "<img src='url'..." without having the domain in the url?

Tags: html, css

It's a silly question but I can't find the right way to do it.

I am making a Wordpress theme for myself and in the CSS, I am specifying image sources with my full domain.

Example:

```
#header {

background: #ffffff url("http://mydomain.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/images/header-bg.jpg");

}
```

I want to make sure that everything works if I install the theme in another domain. What is the proper way to specify the source in this case?

Comment: I think you just remove `http://mydomain.com`

Comment: @WesleyMurch tried both `/wp-content/themes/mytheme/images/header-bg.jpg` and `wp-content/themes/mytheme/images/header-bg.jpg`, didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just have to use **relative paths** to the CSS file, for example if you have the following structure:

```
/mytheme/images/header-bg.jpg
/mytheme/style.css
```

Then at **style.css** make the rule like this:

```
#header {
    background: #ffffff url("images/header-bg.jpg");
}
```

Comment: I get it know. Relative paths. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Nice, then select this as the answer.

Comment: Yes, waiting 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

As Wesley had said before - just remove `http://mydomain.com`

And you need to work out a correct relative path to images catalog. I suppose your css is in `wp-content/themes/mytheme/css`, so i would change it to:

```
#header {
    background: #ffffff url("../images/header-bg.jpg");
}
```